# Use : in list-comprehension

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

Im am trying to write a function, which takes a list and returns a list of all sublists.

Unfortunately my solution doesn't compile and I don't understand why.

My idea is to use take and drop in a list-comprehension and to generate in every iteration from 0 to the length of the list two sublists.

```
sublists:: [a] -> [[a]]
sublists xs = [ as:bs | i <-[0..length xs], as <- (take i xs), bs <- drop (length xs - i) xs]
```

Comment: In the future, please _post the error_. The compiler provides useful information, and you are making us guess about what that could be, or copy your code in our GHC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` prepends an element and a list. Your `as` and `bs` are instead both lists.

You probably need concatenation, as in `as ++ bs`.

It seems that you will find other issues, but this should be the first thing to fix.